# Unable to run my .net core app in local as well as on server with IIS

Tags: api, asp.net-core, iis

I created a .net core api (version 2.2.0) and I'm getting the following error when I try to run on IIS.

> The application process failed to start The application process
>   started but then stopped The application process started but failed to
>   listen on the configured port

I verified my web config and it appears to have correct set of values.Enabled logging and log file comes as empty.

Event log shows the following error.

[image]

I installed hosting bundle and checked still getting same error. Also tried giving permission to IIS_IUSRS to the output folder. It didn't make any difference. Having said that error code "'0x80004005' " suggests a permission error. Still couldn't figure it out. Appreciate any help ! 
Web config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApi.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>`enter code here`
<!--ProjectGuid: 4d7644bb-9348-46f9-8397-95f01e03d599-->
```

Comment: Run the basic diagnostics to rule out common issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you publish the site properly in iis. Your site root folder has enough permission to access it by iis. assign the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site folder. your application pool identity is set application pool identity or local system. anonymous authentication is enabled. and you installed the iis asp.net feature. make sure your site binding is correct and the application pool is using correct .net version and running under integrated application pool.

The reason behind the error message

> The HTTP Error 502.5 - Bad Gateway and HTTP Error 502.5 - Process
>   Failure error messages occur in ASP.NET Core when IIS fails to execute
>   the dotnet process.

- .NET Core Runtime is not installed
- web.config file has not been transformed

To resolve this issue you could refer one the below-suggested way:

1. Install the .NET Core Runtime

The most common reason for this to occur is when you haven't installed the .NET Core runtime on the server.

You can download the latest .NET Core runtime from Microsoft's [.NET download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).

After installing Bundle stop iis and start again.

**Publish a Self-Contained Deployment**

If you don't want to install the .NET Core Runtime. An alternative for .NET Core web applications is to publish them in the Self-Contained deployment mode, which includes the required .NET Runtime files alongside your application.

[image]

If you go with this option, you'll also need to choose a target runtime: win-x86, win-x64, osx-x64, or linux-x64. Because self-contained deployments are not portable.

2. Transform your web.config file

Another reason for this error to occur is when you deploy an untransformed web.config file.

This is likely to be your issue if you had a previously working web application and merely deployed a new version of it.

In ASP.NET Core applications, the web.config file contains a handler that directs requests to the AspNetCoreModule and an aspNetCore element that defines and configures the ASP.NET Core process to execute your web application.

Here is a minimal web.config file for an ASP.NET Core application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
        stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The issue is The untransformed web.config contains the variables %LAUNCHER_PATH% and %LAUNCHER_ARGS% rather than the correct paths. When IIS tries to run ASP.NET Core, it uses %LAUNCHER_PATH% and %LAUNCHER_ARGS% rather than the correct path and arguments.
To fix the HTTP Error 502.5 in ASP.NET Core, you need to transform the web.config and replace the untransformed web.config file on the IIS web server.

steps to transform web.config file:

This transformation takes place when you choose to publish your web application. The transformed web.config ends up in the published output folder. Therefore, you simply need to publish your web application and copy the resulting web.config file onto the server.

In a transformed web.config file, the aspNetCore element will look something like this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

%LAUNCHER_PATH% has been replaced by dotnet and %LAUNCHER_ARGS% has been replaced by the path to the main web application dll .\MyApplication.dll.

links:

[Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I tried all given suggestion. Unfortunately Im still getting the same error. Still the log file comes as empty. So can't get any clue even. I had a doubt about .net core version conflict. So I tried with self-contained. No luck.

Comment: Also tried executing "dotnet .\myapp.dll" from command prompt. it didn't work. Same issue with "dotnet .\myapp.exe" for self-contained deployment as well.

Comment: you could try to use process monitor [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and did you face the same issue if you use  .net core 2.1?

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks ! By the way I noticed one strange thing. When I had     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" /> in the web.config it gives this error "Application '/LM/W3SVC/8/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\outputpath\' failed to load clr and managed application. CLR worker thread exited prematurely" When I changed that to     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" /> it throws the error I mentioned initially.

Comment: I believe the correct value should be AspNetCoreModuleV2 since I use .net core 2.2?

Comment: Could you please share your web.config file setting and try to use `netstat -an` command to check if there is some other process use that port by which you are trying to access your site.

Comment: No other process running on the given port. Sure. I'll update the original post with web config.

Comment: Finally I found that the way I read my appsettings file caused trouble. It worked when run from command line and IIS express though. After I corrected it works fine in local as well as on server. Thank you very much for the help !

Comment: @Taru If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.